# Suggestion regarding which layout to use while implementing GUI in java

Tags: java, user-interface

I have been working on my assignment and I need a help regarding which layout to choose while designing the label combo box and buttons using java GUI.  I want things to be done in a particular manner where in one  horizontal line I need labels followed by combo box followed by button in second horizontal line I want the same things with one extra button and so on for third and fourth horizontal line. Actually my concern is that I am very much new to GUI and I need a suggestion which layout to choose and how to implement it

thanks in advance

Comment: I would start with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Don't think  yourself limited to using just one layout. Often you'll want to nest JPanels, each one using a relatively simply layout. I suggest avoiding the complex layouts such as GridBagLayout and GroupLayout.

Comment: So read the tutorial and then experiment and play with your GUI which is the best way to get a decent feel for the layouts. Then if you're still stuck, come on back with your code, images of what you get and what you're trying to get, and we'll help  you more.

Comment: thanks I will surely turn back to you but I am new here as well and I have reputation of 8 if I have reputation of 10 I can post a image file of what I need to achieve anyways thanks again for helping me out

Comment: Then consider posting a small compilable and runnable program that shows what you're trying right now.

Comment: thanks a lot for you suggestions I am self implementing the group layout and if I will stuck some where will turn back here

Answer (score 0):

I would go with GroupLayout (use NetBeans, it has a very good GUI builder, that makes UI creation easy). If you want to try more sophisticated solution, you may check JGoodies or MigLayout.

Comment: @Hardy: And I strongly urge you not to follow this advice on GroupLayout. Learn and use the basic ones first, then sure use GroupLayout or the downloadable layouts if need be, but first understand well the simple layout managers: BorderLayout, FlowLayout, BoxLayout, GridLayout.